# Restricting injection from a bean definition, not from the autowiring end (bean not injectable implictly)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autowired

Is there any annotation/trick in Spring that marks a @Configuration @Bean as injectable only on strictly qualified @Autowireds?

I'd like my bean to be qualified in a way that only those that specifically call for its @Qualifer can inject it. It's indeed a mechanism for controlling where is it going to be able to be autowired, with no ambiguity nor arbitrary decisions depending on available beans in the context.

So my bean would never be autowired as a side-effect out-of-my control without me actively marking the injecting as expecting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control bean creation with **@Conditional** annotation.

Also if you need real control of using bean you can create some annotation like  @ConroledByQualifer and use this annotation instead of standard spring component annotation , or extension for one (like service , repository .... ) . 
So spring can't process it for autowired as one don't know how to handling it.

You need add **custom BeanPostProcessor** that will work with @ConroledByQualifer - create it and inject. So your custom bean will be processed only by BeanPostProcessor  for @ConroledByQualifer and not custom spring BeanPostProcessors.